# Kubernetes getting IP from Ingress (Oracle Cloud)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

My question is a duplicate of this question: [nginx ingress controller forward source ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968806/nginx-ingress-controller-forward-source-ip)

Though the accepted answer there is a [Helm repository](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) that is now deprecated and does not solve the problem of forwarding the user IP.

I followed the official [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupingresscontroller.htm) and by checking the file `deploy.yaml` one can see that the policy is already set to `Local` by default:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
```

Though when checking the logs with `kubectl logs POD_NAME`, I always get a `10.0.20.X` visiting the endpoint, and never my real IP. Am I mistaken somewhere? How do I forward the user IP?

Comment: Please run this command `kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx -o json | grep "externalTrafficPolicy"` to make sure it's deployed with `local` flag. I got a positive result when I deployed what you described. First internal IP, after changed to `local` I got `real` client IP.

Comment: By running your command I get `"externalTrafficPolicy": "Local"` 
How did you test the `real` client IP?

Comment: Though it is also true that I get `"f:externalTrafficPolicy": {}`

Comment: How I tested it: I created a GKE cluster with 1 node, installed `ingress-nginx`, created and expose simple `nginx` deployment. Then I accessed loadbalancer from my laptop and curl within the cloud, I got the same IP address. Next I edited the `ingress-nginx-controller` service and switched `externalTrafficPolicy` from Cluster to Local. Then accessed this loadbalancer again and got two different IPs, one of them is public IP of my laptop hence it works.

Comment: What you can do else is to try `kubectl edit svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx` and if there's `Local` and not `Cluster`, then it's set up correctly. However in [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) it's said `supported in GCE/Google Kubernetes Engine environments)` so there's a chance Oracle cloud can't recognise this flag and skips it. You can reach out to their support to ask about it.

Comment: When performing that command, it is set to `Local`. Well, thanks. I will reach out to their support

Comment: Okay, please update me on what they will come up with.

Comment: After a solid restart of the service, the IP started to be forwarded to my node application. Now it is just to figure out how `Ingress` can also access it. I will shortly update the answer, as soon as I get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issues (not being able to see Real IP) with launching a Loadbalancer service when the annotation service.beta.kubernetes.io/oci-load-balancer-backend-protocol: is not set to HTTP.

I suggest you try launching the Ingress-Controller service with this annotation and see if it makes any difference.